# Conditionals: Main clause in negative

Tags: conditional-constructions

Do the rules on conditional constructions depend in any way on whether the main-clause is in negative?

Here is one example:

> We are trying to write-down all the steps, so that if another person
> wants to work on the code a year from now, they **will not** need to
> re-do everything from scratch.

Does the application of "will not" sound natural in the above sentence?

Comment: The simple answer is no. Your example is fine.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The example from ther question:

> We are trying to write-down all the steps, so that if another person wants to work on the code a year from now, they will not need to re-do everything from scratch.

is perfectly natural. A fluent speaker might well say or write this, and would understand it. That the sentence is framed in a negative way does not affect the form of the conditional. If this is reworded to a positive phrasing, such as:

> We are trying to write-down all the steps, so that if another person wants to work on the code a year from now, they will be able to easily understand the existing structure.

the conditional form is unchanged.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable help! I have a follow-up question, if you don't mind. Which of the following do you think is more natural? The sentence I provided in my original question or the following altered version that uses zero conditional with simple present tense used in both 'if' and 'main' clauses:

_We are trying to write-down all the steps, so that if another person wants to work on the code a year from now, they **need not** re-do everything from scratch._